# How can I block any interaction on MapView?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I'm designing a Slide Navigation Panel due to that [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift).

Everything works fine. Now I want to go further and work on some UX issues.
This is how my app look like now. But still I can manipulate MapView. My goal is to do two things:

1) Prevent all interaction with MapView, such as scaling and moving

2) Close navigation panel, while tapping on viewController with map.

[image]

The main file for controlling this two controlller is containerViewController. Here is the source code for it:

```
    import UIKit
import QuartzCore

enum SlideOutState {
    case BothCollapsed
    case LeftPanelExpanded
}

class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {

    var centerNavigationController: UINavigationController!
    var centerViewController: ViewController!

    var currentState: SlideOutState = .BothCollapsed {
        didSet {
            let shouldShowShadow = currentState != .BothCollapsed
            showShadowForCenterViewController(shouldShowShadow)
        }
    }

    var leftViewController: SidePanelViewController?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    centerViewController = UIStoryboard.centerViewController()
    centerViewController.delegate = self

    // wrap the centerViewController in a navigation controller, so we can push views to it
    // and display bar button items in the navigation bar
    centerNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)
    view.addSubview(centerNavigationController.view)
    addChildViewController(centerNavigationController)

    centerNavigationController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

  }

}

let centerPanelExpandedOffset: CGFloat = 60

extension ContainerViewController: CenterViewControllerDelegate {

    func toggleLeftPanel() {

        let notAlreadyExpanded = (currentState != .LeftPanelExpanded)

        if notAlreadyExpanded {
            addLeftPanelViewController()
        }

        animateLeftPanel(shouldExpand: notAlreadyExpanded)

    }



    func addLeftPanelViewController() {

        if (leftViewController == nil) {
            leftViewController = UIStoryboard.leftViewController()
            leftViewController!.categories = Category.allCats()

            addChildSidePanelController(leftViewController!)
        }

    }

    func addChildSidePanelController(sidePanelController: SidePanelViewController) {
        view.insertSubview(sidePanelController.view, atIndex: 0)

        addChildViewController(sidePanelController)
        sidePanelController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }


    func animateLeftPanel(shouldExpand shouldExpand: Bool) {

        if (shouldExpand) {
            currentState = .LeftPanelExpanded

            animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: CGRectGetWidth(centerNavigationController.view.frame) - centerPanelExpandedOffset)
        } else {
            animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: 0) { finished in
                self.currentState = .BothCollapsed

                self.leftViewController!.view.removeFromSuperview()
                self.leftViewController = nil;
            }
        }

    }

    func animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition targetPosition: CGFloat, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)! = nil) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.centerNavigationController.view.frame.origin.x = targetPosition
            }, completion: completion)
    }

    func showShadowForCenterViewController(shouldShowShadow: Bool) {
        if (shouldShowShadow) {
            centerNavigationController.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
        } else {
            centerNavigationController.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
        }
    }

}


private extension UIStoryboard {
  class func mainStoryboard() -> UIStoryboard { return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()) }

  class func leftViewController() -> SidePanelViewController? {
    return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftViewController") as? SidePanelViewController
  }


  class func centerViewController() -> ViewController? {
    return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CenterViewController") as? ViewController
  }

}
```

My idea is to create variable that stands for active side panel and write a function, that will solve my issues:

I see something like that:

```
func blockCenterView() {

    let AlreadyExpanded = (currentState = .LeftPanelExpanded)

    if AlreadyExpanded {
        //no idea what to write here
    }
}
```

Am I right, or there exist other variants for solving that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code whereever you want to stop interaction with mapView

```
mapView.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

To enable it back,

```
mapView.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

> Note : mapView is an instance of MKMapView

**PS**

**SWRevealViewController**

Source : [Github](https://goo.gl/40RJrq)

Step By Step Tutorial : [More Flexible Slide View](http://goo.gl/uFq7pl)

This is what I was able to create using this awesome framework

[image]

App Link : [AirMate on AppStore](https://goo.gl/D0VJP3)

Comment: `userInteraction` doesn't work on `MKMapView`.

Comment: sorry, its `userInteractionEnabled`

Comment: The problem is, unlike on other `UIView`s, `userInteractionEnabled` does not block all user interaction on `MKMapView`.

Comment: try adding `self.mapView.userInteractionEnabled`, as I'm able to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the following properties to `false`

```
mapView.zoomEnabled = false
mapView.scrollEnabled = false
mapView.userInteraction = false
```

Also check the Interface Builder for the user Interactions:[image]